# Why is NSDecimalNumber crashing when I try to use decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I'm trying to retrieve a number from user defaults and multiply it. Here's my code:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDecimalNumber *current = [prefs  objectForKey:@"account"];
NSDecimalNumber *multiplier = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.15"];
NSDecimalNumber *floo = [current decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy: multiplier];
```

It's giving me this really hideous crash as soon as it hits the `floo` line. The huge spew of error gobbledygook begins with:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFNumber decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:]: unrecognized selector 
sent to instance 0x8c7b1e0'
```

This seemed like a very simple thing, but my goodness! What's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've assigned the value of `[prefs objectForKey:@"account"]` to an NSDecimalNumber variable, but the actual value is an NSNumber, not an NSDecimalNumber.  When you try to call `-decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:` on that object, your program crashes, because that object doesn't know what to do with that method.

You can convert an NSNumber to an NSDecimalNumber like this:

```
NSNumber *number = /* ... */
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = 
    [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[number decimalValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Better may be to use an archiver, like storing the object as:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:current] forKey:@"account"];
```

and retrieving it:

```
current = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"account"] ];
```

That is more reliable I think than seeing that you actually have an __NSCFNumber back, and converting that.